# Sram cranksets, are there differences other than weights betwen models?

Tags: sram

I'm trying out different crank arm length 165/170

Are there differences between sx/nx/gx cranksets other than weights?

(I'm wondering if I should pick one of sx/nx/gx and differentiate arm length only..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some models of SX cranksets are square taper, which will be significantly heavier than a external bearing style crankset. I believe the newer revisions of SX have converted to DUB though, bringing them inline with the rest of the EAGLE lineup.

For GX, you can choose between aluminum and carbon, while X01 and XX1 only come in carbon. SX and NX only come in aluminum. I wouldn’t be surprised if SX DUB has a heavier steel axle as well. NX and above should have an aluminum axle.

Answer (score 1):

The major difference is the materials, such as steel or aluminum chainring, the level of aluminum used in the crankarms and the way they are machined. All of which does lend to the overall weight of the crankset. See below for a side by side comparison as well and pictures of each in which you can see the difference in the chainrings and the amount of machining in the backside of the crankarms.

Notice the NX and GX use the aluminum XSync 2 chainring, while the SX uses the Steel Eagle chainring. All of which have the same tooth profile to run Eagle chains.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]